# How to unjoin then join to the domain in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, dns, password-encryption

We need to unjoin then rejoin to our domain.
I tried the following:

```
$c = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem
$Credentials = Get-Credential

$c.UnJoinDomainOrWorkGroup("$($Credentials.Password)", "$($Credentials.UserName)", 0)
```

So far so good. Then try to rejoin:

```
$c.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup("mydomain", "$($Credentials.Password)", "$($Credentials.UserName)", $null, 3)
```

It returns with 1312 returnvalue.
But when I try to use my password as a plain text it works. :O

Why don't work this password method here? I don't want to use it as a plain text.

Thank you all.

Comment: My guess is that it isn't even using the credentials in the first instance since you aren't actually passing the password to the method.  Instead you are passing the string "System.Security.SecureString", which is what PowerShell gives you if you try to read the password back the way you are.  You can get the actual clear text password like this: "$($Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password)".  Incidentally, wrapping in quotes and using a subexpression is not needed since the values are already strings.

Comment: First : why aren't you using the Add-Computer and Remove-Computer CMDlets to do the domain disjoin/join part? Also as a side note : removing a machine from the domain and readding it (assuming you are rejoining to the same domain, usually for trust relationship issues) is considered a BAD practice (again, assuming to repair a trust relationship). If you want to repair a broken trust relationship you can use Test-ComputerSecureChannel with the -Repair parameter.

Comment: boxdog, your solution is perfect! :)
bluuf: Description: We are at enterprise environment. We newly installed some computer via PXE. After setup finishes and try to log in to the system with domain User the windows throw the following message:  "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"  . It is interesting that we can make changes remotely with adm privileges. So the GPO applied successfully and this computer is joined the domain but can't log on. Maybe the trust relationship has broken that you mentioned. I tried your cmdlet but it was failed.